# How to change dividing point to comma in decimal value in Highcharts pie chart?

Tags: highcharts

I use Hightchart and I need to show comma instead of point in decimal value to be correct German format.
My code: `pointFormat = "{point.name}: <b>{point.percentage}</b><br/>"`
Do we have any setting or any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the formatter?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                //format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {parseFloat(point.percentage)} %'
                formatter: function() {
                    let pointName = this.point.name
                  let pointPercentage = parseFloat(this.point.percentage).toFixed(2).toLocaleString().replace(".", ",");
                
                return `${pointName}: ${pointPercentage}%`
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 61.41,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
        }, {
            name: 'Internet Explorer',
            y: 11.84
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.85
        }, {
            name: 'Edge',
            y: 4.67
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.18
        }, {
            name: 'Sogou Explorer',
            y: 1.64
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 1.6
        }, {
            name: 'QQ',
            y: 1.2
        }, {
            name: 'Other',
            y: 2.61
        }]
    }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 320px; 
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}
.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table thead tr, .highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}


input[type="number"] {
    min-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        Pie charts are very popular for showing a compact overview of a
        composition or comparison. While they can be harder to read than
        column charts, they remain a popular choice for small datasets.
    </p>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!